# Why won't this standard Reg Ex work in PHP's ereg function

Tags: php, html, regex

I am a bit of a newbie to Reg Ex and don't fully understand the difference between the different flavors. However, I have a basic Reg Ex that works when I try it via the UNIX system (vi and grep) but not when I try to to use it in PHP's ereg functions. I suspect there is something different about the PHP ereg function that is making this not work:

```
<?php
$string = 'Feugiat <em>hendrerit</em> sit iriuredolor aliquam.';
$string = ereg_replace("<em\b[^>]*>(.*?)</em>","\\1",$string);
echo $string;
?>
```

I would like this to output **Feugiat hendrerit sit iriuredolor aliquam.** without the em tags. However it just returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's ereg functions use a very limited regex flavor called [POSIX ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).  My [flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) indicates all that this flavor lacks compared with modern flavors.

In your case, the word boundary \b is not supported.  A strict POSIX implementation will flag \b as an error.

Your solution is to use the preg functions instead:

```
preg_replace('!<em\b[^>]*>(.*?)</em>!', '$1', $string);
```

Compared with other answers you've received: Don't escape the backslash in \b, and use $1 for the replacement.  preg_replace uses a different replacement text syntax than ereg_replace.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to escape the backslash:

```
$string = ereg_replace("<em\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</em>","\\1",$string);
```

This is because `\b` in a PHP string means something different from a `\b` in a regular expression. Using `\\` in the PHP string passes through a single backslash to `ereg_replace()`. This is the same reason you need to use double backslash in the replacement string `"\\1"`.

Depending on your application, you may also want to consider the possibility that your input `$string` does not contain any `<em>` tags. In that case, the above statements would result in an empty string, which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: Alternately, you could use single-quoted strings so that there's no interpretation of the contents of the string.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. \\1 is not a backreference in the preg_replace replacement text. $1 is.

Comment: single quotes still use escape sequences (backslash), it just doesn't evaluate $

Answer (score 2):

If all you're using the regular expression for is to remove the html tags, perhaps php's strip_tags() function would be more appropriate.

[php.net manual entry](http://us.php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: Yeah, totally, but I was more just bringing this up as an example, b/c I didn't understand how PHP uses RegEx. And I can imagine a situation where I only want to remove one specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

ereg_replace does not support the word boundary assertion (\b) or non-greedy modifier (*?). PEZ is right, you should probably be using preg.

```
preg_replace('!<em\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</em>!', '$1', $string)
```

The extra backslash is not strictly necessary because PHP does not replace \b, but it is a good idea to always escape backslashes in a string literal.

Comment: Why did you use the ! instead of the % to encapsulate the preg? Is there an advantage to this or is it just preference? I have the same question about your use of $1 vs \\1

Comment: They're both personal preference, but most regex flavors use the $1 form for capture-group references in the replacement string, so you should favor that form.  You can also use ${1} to avoid collisions with other digits in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a good idea to avoid `ereg` for future compatibility. It looks like it's been depreciated in php6 according to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-future/?ca=dgr-lnxw01PHP-Future).

> The ereg extension, which supports Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) regular expressions, is being removed from core PHP support.

Answer (score 1):

If removing `<em>` tags is your intention, I would recommend the following:

```
<?php
  $string = 'Feugiat <em>hendrerit</em> sit iriuredolor aliquam.';
  $string = ereg_replace("</?em\\b[^>]*>", "", $string);
  echo $string;
?>
```

[Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375563/why-wont-this-standard-reg-ex-work-in-phps-ereg-function#375568) is right about the escaping of backslashes in a PHP string. You need to do it to get a literal backslash into your regex pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

I have never understood ereg_ and always use preg. If you add the backslash like Greg suggests and change to preg_ it will compile.

```
$string = preg_replace('%<em\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</em>%','\\1',$string);
```

Edit: I agree with others here that this particular approach might not be ideal for the problem. But still, preg_ is most often the way to go when using regexes in PHP.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  \\1 is not a backreference in the preg_replace replacement text.  $1 is.

Answer (score 1):

ereg doesn't handle the \b boundary stuff, as far as I know, while the preg does. 
Also, I think the double quoting on the regex may cause problems with the backslashs